# MS Access Sequence jumped when invalid data is entered

Tags: sql-server, sequence

I have created a SQL Server Sequence (Backend)

**SEQUENCE**

```
CREATE SEQUENCE [dbo].[Airlines_Mast_SEQ]
 AS [int]
 START WITH 1
 INCREMENT BY 1
 MINVALUE 1
 MAXVALUE 99999
 CACHE 
GO
```

**TABLE**

```
 CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Airlines_Mast](

    [ID] [int] NOT NULL DEFAULT NEXT VALUE FOR [Airlines_Mast_SEQ] PRIMARY KEY,
    [Airlines_ID]  AS ('AS'+right('00000'+CONVERT([varchar],[ID]),(6))) PERSISTED NOT NULL,
    [Airlines_CODE] [varchar](4) NOT NULL,
    [Airlines_Name] [nvarchar](100) NOT NULL,
    [Airlines_GSTIN] [varchar](15) NOT NULL,
    [Airlines_Address1] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [Airlines_Pincode] [varchar](10) NULL,
    [Legal_Name] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [Type] [varchar](15) NULL,
    [Airlines_Active] [bit] NOT NULL
    ) ON [PRIMARY]
```

**MS Access(Front End)**

I have created a Form in MS Access using table Airlines_Mast , while  entering data in Form

(1) When Data is correctly entered for **a** Record in one Go then SEQUENCE  is maintained but,
(2) When invalid Data is entered  multiple time for **a** Record after validation check then SEQUENCE  got jumped to next sequence.

Kindly suggest to maintain the sequence without Jump.

Comment: Thats how sequences work, they don't get recovered again on failure.

Comment: SEQUENCES and IDENTITY are transactional unaware because of concurrency. If not every value given by the autoincrement of the system must lock the complete code and noone will be able to insert concurrently

Comment: Kindly suggest, any alternative Solution